# Default value for options object in class constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created a class and I would like to set some default options for values in case the user does not supply any arguments. I recently went from a constructor that took multiple parameters to an object because I believe it helps readability when the user is creating a new instance of the class.

**Here is how I was doing it before:**

```
module.exports = class User {
    constructor(name = "Joe", age = 47) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

const User = require("./user");

const user = new User(); // Defaults to "Joe" and 47
```

In reality, my class has more parameters than that and the readability when using it becomes tough. So to solve this I switched to an options object that works much better but I can't seem to put default values. When I try to use `this.name` it says `this.name = options.name || "Joe" Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` even though I thought I set the default to "Joe"

**Here is how  I'm doing it now:**

```
module.exports = class User {
    constructor(options) {
        this.name = options.name || "Joe";
        this.age = options.age || 47;
    }
}

const User = require("./user");

const user = new User();
```

Comment: `options` is undefined, you are trying to access `undefied.name`. You could set a default of `{}` for `options` in the signature of your constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either set a default value for options, i.e `{}`.

```
class User {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        this.name = options.name || "Joe";
        this.age = options.age || 47;
    }
}
```

or first check for `options` to be truthy and then access the value.

```
class User {
    constructor(options) {
        this.name = options && options.name || "Joe";
        this.age = options && options.age || 47;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the ES6 way, very nice. You could also use destructuring to extract the variables from `options` :)

Answer (score 7):

You actually just need a oneliner:

```
const defaultUser = {
  name: "Joe",
  age: 47
};

module.exports = class User {
  constructor(options) {
     Object.assign(this, defaultUser,  options)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change to a configuration pattern, you can still keep your default parameter syntax:

```
module.exports = class User {
    constructor({ name = "Joe", age = 47 } = {}) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

const User = require("./user");

const user = new User(); // Defaults to "Joe" and 47
```

Comment: This was the one I was waiting for :P   Object Destructuring with Default Parameters :D

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a default for the object itself.

```
module.exports = class User {
    constructor(options) {
        options = options || {}
        this.name = options.name || "Joe";
        this.age = options.age || 47;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I think I understand it now, so if options isn't specified when the class is initialized, it doesn't exist so that's why the error is being thrown?

Comment: You might not want to set `options` as an instance-variable

Comment: @clentfort I think I've seen it done this way before but I didn't understand it at the time. What is the different between this method and the first method in your answer?

Comment: My first answer uses new language features, this is the "classic" way. If you want to use this code, beware that you assign `options` to the instance variable `options`, so it's available anywhere via `this.options`. This might not be desired.

Comment: @clentfort I've updated the answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy The default parameter that clentfort used is ES6 syntax to do the same thing. It is very elegant, and if you are transpiling your JS I would go with that, but if you are concerned about compatibility the old school way does the exact same thing.